# The meaning of " swing off in graceful curves"

Tags: meaning

The langurs, the big gray-whiskered monkeys of the Himalayas, were, naturally, the first, for they are alive with curiosity; and when they had upset the beggingbowl, and rolled it round the floor, and tried their teeth on the brass-handled crutch, and made faces at the antelope skin, they decided that the human being who sat so still was harmless. At evening, they would leap down from the pines, and beg with their hands for things to eat, **and then swing off in graceful curves.**

This is from "The Miracle of Puram Bhagat " by Rudyard Kipling.
https://www.kiplingsociety.co.uk/tale/the-miracle-of-purun-bhagat.htm

I don't understand the meaning of---
and then swing off in graceful curves.

I am glad if someone would kindly teach me.

Answer (score 2):

"Swing off" just means to travel in a swinging motion.

Since these are monkeys, I imagine that they climb back up the pine trees and travel by swinging from the branches.  The swinging motion is described as "graceful" and as they are swinging they travel in curves; so they "swing in graceful curves".

Comment: @James.K Thank you very much for your precise answer. I is so helpful for me.

Comment: I would add that "off" in this context means "away" or "to somewhere else".